# How to customize the binding expression in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a jcheckbox, when I select it, must disable a jComboBox.

I try to negate the binding expression in this mode:

```
${!enabled}
```

but doesn't work, the java application doesn't start. What's the trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go with selected property not with enabled property of checkbox.

And you have to bind for combobox's enabled property to checkbox's selected property.

```
${!selected}
```

[image]